# check if an air android app is installed on the mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an air application and inside it I have many package ids of another air apps. I want to know if specific id app is installed or not on the phone. how can I do that? 
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this extension https://github.com/StickSports/ANE-Can-Open-URL 
It's quite old and it might not work as expected, but is worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you... I think you are the one who understand my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what you are asking for, so I'll show you how to publish your app.

Any and every android app is packaged in an "apk".
In the latest version of Flash Pro, you can publish an app for android through Adobe AIR.
Under the "development" tab in the publish settings window, you can connect a phone to the computer (I recommend USB), and have the app automatically install onto your phone.
There are many tutorials out there for that, so I'll finish there. Just google about apks and you will find plenty of info about how to make them.

You mentioned "ids". This is just used in android stores and such, to my knowledge. Check applications on your android settings app, and you should find it. If you are looking for apks, check the "my files" app of install a file managing app to search for it.

Hope that helped :) Reply if that is not your question.

Comment: no, you're not right! :) I know how to publish an app. So I just want to Invoke another air app from my app and I managed to do that, but I want to know if app that I want to lauch is installed on phone. And for that I need a method to find if an app is installed or not (the app I want to invoke is mine for that I know the package id) hope you understand my bad english. thx for replay

Comment: I need something like this, but to be coded in as3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213525/determining-if-user-installed-an-app-air-as3   check last answer

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I can't help you then. I am not sure how to do that. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: yes! let's say you had installed 2 apps of mine (A and B), now I have this third app C in whitch I want to implement invokation of A and B . So I have to check first if you had A or B installed in your phone, and after I have confirmation, launch the specific app...

Comment: No problem, at least you have tried to help me. thanks

Comment: Sorry I can't help you any further - but I looked it up myself and found something that is related to interacting with other apps here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html